# ReplaceAll (/.) not working as expected

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, semantic-matching

I am trying to replace some variables in the form of `n*wt` with `wt`. However, I came across some cases where the `/.` gives unexpected results. For example, `-Cos[\[Pi]/6 - 6*wt] + 7/5 Cos[\[Pi]/6 + 6* wt] /. {6*wt -> wt}` would give me the result `-Cos[\[Pi]/6 - 6 wt] + 7/5 Cos[\[Pi]/6 + wt]`. It seems that the replacement worked for the second half of the expression, but not the first half. Could anyone explain why is this and what would be a reliable way to do this?

Comment: Evaluate `-Cos[\[Pi]/6 - 6*wt] // FullForm`

Comment: adding to Edmunds comment: it is vital to understand that the Mathematica pattern matching is working with the internal representation (`FullForm`) of expressions, it is not based on mathematical identities.

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
-Cos[π/6 - 6*wt] + 7/5 Cos[π/6 + 6*wt] /. {a_ wt :> Sign[a] wt}
```

or, if you want to replace only coefficients 6 or -6,:

```
-Cos[π/6 - 6*wt] + 7/5 Cos[π/6 + 6*wt] /. {(a : 6 | -6) wt :> Sign[a] wt}
```

to get

> -Cos[[Pi]/6 - wt] + 7/5 Cos[[Pi]/6 + wt]

Answer (score 8):

Mathematica is generally more reliable if your replacement is for a single variable rather than an expression, such as:

```
-Cos[π/6 - 6*wt] + 7/5 Cos[π/6 + 6*wt] /. {wt -> wt/6}
(*7/5 Cos[wt + π/6] - Cos[π/6 - wt]*)
```

Answer (score 4):

you may try something like:

```
    -Cos[\[Pi]/6 - 6*wt] + 7/5 Cos[\[Pi]/6 + 6*wt] /. Cos[x_ + y_] :> Cos[x + y/6]
```